# how to hide bootstrap navbar default icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

need add bootstrap  tag to My html file and display My menu items. but I do not need default navbar highlight box and hamburger icon when I visit My site using tab or mobile device.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
<nav>
```

how can do it?

Comment: pls explain more clearly. I still not understand what do you want to do?

Comment: remove it if no need navigation tab /

Comment: actually I need make responsive menu design. include nav tag. But I do not need hamburgar icon and default highlighted nav bar box. because I allready have My own menu item. I need put it in to the nav bar tag to make My menu responsive

Answer (score 1):

**Hello**, just remove those line of code for removing the hamburger:

```
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```

Try to be more specific about the "highlight box", but i assume that you will need some CSS to work around that.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sidbiffi/2rb37wx2/1/) too.

Comment: actually I need make responsive menu design. include nav tag. But I do not need hamburgar icon and default highlighted nav bar box. because I allready have My own menu item. I need put it in to the nav bar tag to make My menu responsive @Sid Biffi

Comment: Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sidbiffi/2rb37wx2/2/) and tell me if that fits your needs, follow the comments to add your things.

Comment: it is ok but problem is My menu item is now not working <a href="#menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>  
                       <div id="menu">
                               <ul>
                                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                               </ul>
          </div></ul>

Comment: You can fork the fiddle and resend it, you shouldn't write code in comments.

Comment: ok if we remove humbergur icon is it working well for responsive design nav bar?

Comment: Of course not, Bootstrap nav is built around the hamburger menu.. you should use their design or build your own media querys.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your properly than please apply "hidden-sm hidden-xs" class to that "li" which you don't want in responsive mode.

Thanks,
Rohan Kacha

Comment: actually I need make responsive menu design. include nav tag. But I do not need hamburgar icon and default highlighted nav bar box. because I allready have My own menu item. I need put it in to the nav bar tag to make My menu responsive @Rohan

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `@media query`. you must define width that you want hidden `nav` in it ,and use of `max-width(The maximum width of the display area)` or `max-device-width(The maximum width of the device)`.

For example :

```
@media all and (max-width : 769px) {
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

if `width` be less than `769px` ,so `nav` is hidden.

```css
@media all and (max-width : 769px) {
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
<nav>
```

Note:use of full page and resize browsers.

Comment: actually I need make responsive menu design. include nav tag. But I do not need hamburgar icon and default highlighted nav bar box. because I allready have My own menu item. I need put it in to the nav bar tag to make My menu responsive @ehsan